# How to create a jquery range slider with one constant value and one variable?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, uislider

[image]

Red one will remain constant, green one needs to be a variable. but it should be able to exceed red one. Is there any suitable plugin? most of the plugins have two values but minimum values cannot exceed max value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the queryui-slider with a fixed min or max value as shown in the examples on their website and adapt the styling, so the slider looks wider as it really is.
To be able to change the red mark by users, you might need some more javascript manipulate / reset the max value of the slider.